# Is there a way to do a contraction offset on a shape in Photoshop without rasterizing it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes, stroke, scale

### So... say I start out with a simple Shape.

(I mean this like a literal, vector Shape, with the capital S. With the grip points.
It's important that I wind up with one in the end, too)

[image: A simple Shape]

Now, I want to do a contraction offset,
such that the outline/silhouette/stroke
is contracted INWARDS, consistently and
the same amount from all directions.

[image: Example of goal]

So, straight out the gate, the shape's
irregularity precludes simply scaling it...

[image]

...even if I DON'T maintain
the aspect ratio, it's still
inconsistent.

[image]

Same goes for just shift-offsetting it.

[image]

Even the old "quadruple cardinal
offset/intersection" trick still can't
do it perfectly.

[image]

Now, I KNOW this can be done in Illustrator...

... which I don't have access to at the moment.

Is there really no way INSIDE PHOTOSHOP to turn this...
[image]
...into this
without having to rasterize the image?

## In response to Scott's (reasonable and excellent answer):

Well (and again, this IS a rather contrived example, but work with me here): the simplest reason as to why not a stacked stroke is simply:

[image]

...if one is after two gradients going in opposite directions. Or possibly:

[image]

...I'm trying to save my stroke for something else.

In reality, though, the real reason is I'm working with SMIL - specifically SVG morphology for the web. So for this (again, contrived) example, say, I want my bow...

[image]

...to "morph" into a butterfly.

[image]

To do this, I need to have the same number of vertices in the starting and ending image. Yes, there are libraries like Greensock that can partially cheat it, but that's not the point. Really, I just want to know if there's a expand or contract for shape paths in PS. Because, and to answer your question, Billy, I don't have access to another tool in this case. I'm not on my rig.

Comment: (To be clear: I know about Select > Modify > Contract, but the only way to apply this to the shape is to rasterize it. Yes, I can mask it, but then I lose the ability to modify the vector shape)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GSDSE. I wouldn't use Photoshop for this. It's vector capabilities are extremely limited. Better to use proper vector software. Illustrator and Inskcape have both have an Offset path effect, which can be expanded/convert to real vectors if required. [An example](https://imgur.com/aMH9iCe).

Comment: Yes, I know. Indeed, since I AM constrained to the tool I'm using (not my call; client's machine), I've been scaling the image up to 4kx4k, rasterizing it, running the standard raster contract, inverting, clearing, then setting the selection and making a work path, which I can then use as a subtract on the source silhouette, and then scale it back down (vector being agnostic of size anyway). I KNOW how to use the tools... I'm just stuck with the (wrong) one I'm using in this case, and was hoping someone might have a better trick than mine.

Comment: I don't see how you are "stuck" with Photoshop.  Inkscape is free, Open Source, and 100% safe. In Inkscape just make sure to convert the offset path effect to vector, using *Path > Object to Path*, then save the finished work as a Plain SVG, and click and drag it into a Photoshop document, it will be imported as a vector Smart Object. The Smart Object can then be rescaled just like a native Photoshop vector, without degradation in quality.

Comment: In this case, I'd been working on a client's machine who, in turn, didn't wish to jump through the hoops required to get their IT department to do a software review to authorize another application for the sole purpose of offsetting a line (a task which I'd already managed to brute force my way through accomplishing anyway). My question here was, quite literally, asking if anyone knew of a way to do this IN PHOTOSHOP, so, should a similar scenario arise again, I'd have one more tool in my holster. I'm not disagreeing with anything you've said... you ARE correct... but it wasn't an option, then

Comment: Point of fact.... last night when I arrived home, I scripted the functionality (Expand Shape, Contract Shape, and Create Stroke With Fill) for PS myself. I'll stick it up in Adobe's extension/plug-in library today or tomorrow for public consumption. Heck, I'll stick a link in the original question (after reviewing SE's ToS; I'm planning on open-sourcing it, so I can't imagine anyone will gripe, but "roads to hell..."). Like I said: I KNOW how to use the tools.. I started in PS in version 2. Not CC2. Not CS2. 2.0. Like, the year they added COLOR. I'd just wondered if I'd overlooked something.

Comment: To me, from your comments Nerdy, it clearly seems like you *know* what you're doing -- just a situation where you couldn't use anything other than PS... and I was indeed envisioning a remote system which, for one reason or another, would not allow installs, or had no direct internet connection.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds - yeah, I understand. However, for future reference, if you ever find yourself in a similar situation with no access to a vector image editor, and no possibility of installing one, there is an online version of Figma, which is free. Works right inside your browser, and can export as SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for specificity:

I'm afraid, to the best of my knowledge, Photoshop offers **no ability** to programmatically expand/contract anything vector-based in order to achieve equidistant offsets.

The *best* one can achieve is always merely "by eye."

This is one area where Photoshop lacks usability in terms of its vector tools.

What I would do if I had no other tools....

- Duplicate original shape
  [image]
- Apply a stroke set to inner align on original to use as a visual *guide*.
- Scale and adjust the path in the duplicate to match the inner stroke edge as closely as possible
  [image]
  [image]
- Highlight both original and duplicate layers and `Merge Shapes` from the layer panel menu
  [image] 
  [image]
- Set the correct Path Interaction options for this merged shape layer
  [image]
  [image]

Far more effort than merely an offset.. but this *will* ultimately end in better results most of the time.

---

Original answer:

ermm... seems like you may be overthinking this. Unless there's some reason you *must* have an inner *path* as opposed to merely the appearance. But then, why would you need the inner path?

Unless I'm missing something, one can merely set a **Fill** and **Stroke** for the shape layer...

[image]

You **can** set the stroke alignment to the `Inside` if you want the shape edges to remain the same...

[image]

---

If you want to be able to adjust the fill *separate* from the stroke, example: apply layer styles to fill, but not the stroke ...

Stack a copy of the shape layer and apply different fill/strokes to the copies.

[image]

- Top Layer - just a black stroke (8pts) aligned on center, no fill
- Bottom layer - Dashed white stroke (6pts) aligned to inside, black fill with diagonal pattern overlay

The black stroke on the top layer created the *appearance* of an inner offset and allows you to add the dashed stroke to the bottom layer.

Comment: Which are totally fair questions. I'll modify my original question to answer yours, and explain further, and I shal endeavor to do so with the (extremely contrived, albeit) example I began with

Comment: I honestly don't think there's a direct solution to actually creating the inner path in Photoshop, @NerdyDeeds - The hurdles you show in the question are there for everyone and I, at least, don't know any method around them other than to use Illustrator rather than Photoshop - at least to create the paths, then copy back to Photoshop as a shape layer. Scaling odd shapes simply *never* creates an equidistant offset in Photoshop and there's no option to offset anything vector based in Photoshop (at least as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: Let me be clear: your answer is both useful and superb. I also don't known of a way other than the one I describe to Billy, above: Set Selection, New Layer Make work path, Cut, Select target layer, Paste, Set Merge Method: Subtract. I was just hoping there was a trick, or it was buried somewhere in the GUI and I was missing it, or an Automate or Script someone might know. I'm going to set you as best answer here regardless, since yours IS a very-well presented and thought out response that likely WILL be of help to someone with less esoteric demands than I. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Also worth noting that a deficiency with SVG for the web is we don't get stroke positioning. And I've experimented at length: https://codepen.io/NerdyDeeds/pen/dyPQEVK. I can fake it, but not if I want to animate it TOO.

Comment: I updated the answer @NerdyDeeds with what I would do specifically in such a situation if I only had access to Photoshop.

Comment: That's  virtually identical to the method I'm using now. Thank you again for such an excellent response. That will 100% help someone out. You've absolutely earned best answer. <3
  (Like I said: I know it's the wrong tool for the job. I suspect the only reason Adobe DOESN'T just merge the two tools and make it a mode toggle is they sell more product this way)

Comment: ... or at least "only answer" `:)`

Comment: Touché. Also: right again!  ~_^

Comment: I tend to excel when I'm the only choice `:)` Good luck with the animation! That stuff is well out of my wheelhouse much of the time.

Comment: So you've got 200k gold rep; you'll prolly know: when I got back to my comp last night, I scripted the functionality (Expand Shape, Contract Shape, and Create Stroke With Fill) for PS myself. Is it OK if I post a link to the (entirely-free, open-source) scripts here, say as an edit to the original question? I'm not  trying to profit off em at all, it just seems like functionality that SHOULD have been there. I'm gonna post the script to Adobe's extension marketplace, so it'll have been vetted and verified as safe. Is it permissible to do that in Stack Exchange?

Comment: @NerdyDeeds It's perfectly okay to link to something you created, just be certain to mention it's yours. Self-promo is fine if A) it answers the question and B) You disclose the resource is yours -- What I would do is post an **answer**, not edit the question. It's fine to answer your own question. You could include the script in the answer so users can copy/paste, if you're okay with that - keeps the answer self-contained and avoids link-rot. Then you can accept your own answer if it's a better answer (I don't care about losing any rep).